# openCV load_object_detect function

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to run a face detection code in openCV and I don't want to use the command prompt to run it but I don't know what to give as an input argument to load_object_detect.
here is the sample from the code:

```
             CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = load_object_detector(argv[2]);
```

In order for the above command to execute the code should be run from the command prompt which I am trying to avoid for now...

All I know is that its input type is const char* cascade_path...

Answer (score 0):

try `argv[2] = whatever path you want to put;`
just before calling the function

Something like this

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

argv[2] = "SuvP";

std::cout<<"Hey "<<argv[2]<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

The output is `Hey SuvP`

The arguments from command line are stored in the array argv. Alternatively we are filling data in the array within the code and not from the command line in this case.

Comment: what if I take input in the main?coz agrv[2] is I guess the second argument given from the command line.@SuvP

Comment: @AaymanKhalid

You can do 

`argv[2] = fileName etc`;

`CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = load_object_detector(argv[2]);` Will work i suuppose.

Comment: Ok but what do I give to load_object_detect?this might be infuriating for you but I am really having a tough time understanding this thing:(   @SuvP

Comment: From [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/object_detection.html?highlight=load_object_detector#cvhaarfeature-cvhaarclassifier-cvhaarstageclassifier-cvhaarclassifiercascade)

I understand 

`CvHaarClassifierCascade* load_object_detector( const char* cascade_path )`
 requires a String, possibly a filename. I am not well versed with the openCV API to point out exactly what is needed by that function

Comment: @AaymanKhalid [this](http://opencvfacedetect.blogspot.in/2010/10/face-detectionfollowed-by-eyesnose.html) can be helpful . Maybe it requires some .xml file

Comment: there is one more thing,now that I am runnning this code,It gives me this error:Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvLoad referenced in function "struct CvHaarClassifierCascade * __cdecl load_object_detector(char const *)" (?load_object_detector@@YAPAUCvHaarClassifierCascade@@PBD@Z) OpenCV_basics.obj OpenCV_basics

Comment: I found out that I am supposed to give the path of the xml files residing in the "haarcascades" folder...!

Comment: @Aayman That would be helpful for me too :P incase i decide to use OpenCV someday!